# Avoid firing trigger by another trigger in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

my problem is as follows:

- Table A contains list of "Tasks"
- Table B contains "TaskProgress" - just an information about time spent on  task, user ID, task ID and note

On table A (Tasks), I have trigger, which updates datetime of last change - column DateChanged (intended to capture datetime of edits made by user)

On table B (TaskProgress) I have trigger, which updates total time spent on a task (sum all times for given Task_ID and update column TotalTime in table A)

I wish to update DateChanged in Table A only when user mades the update (which is every time except when trigger on table B updates TotalTime)

So I wonder, whether there is a way how to tell the database not to fire TRIGGER when updating the values in another trigger.

```
/* set date of last change and date od closing of task */
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_tasks_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON tasks
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET new.DateChanged = NOW();
    IF new.Status_ID = 3 THEN
        SET new.DateClosed = NOW();
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

/* set total time spent on task */
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_taskprogress_insert
AFTER INSERT ON taskprogress
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE sumtime TIME;
    SET @sumtime := (SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `timeSpent` ) ) )
        FROM taskprogress WHERE Task_ID = new.Task_ID);
    UPDATE `tasks` SET TimeReal = @sumtime WHERE ID = new.Task_ID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

I use MySQL 5.5.40

Thanks, zbynek

Comment: Do the user updates on tasks involve modifying the TimeReal column or not?

Comment: No, user is not supposed to update TimeReal and I would like to avoid sending time from client machines to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check to verify that the update implies a new TimeReal value,since only the second trigger updates that column.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER before_tasks_update 
BEFORE UPDATE ON tasks
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF new.TimeReal=old.TimeReal THEN SET new.DateChanged = NOW();
    END IF;
    IF new.TimeReal=old.TimeReal AND new.Status_ID = 3 THEN
        SET new.DateClosed = NOW();
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: great! simple and does not require setting global variables and such